# Angular 7 Interceptor

Tags: angular, typescript

I am calling an API which is redirecting to external url doing the authentication and again redirecting to my home page and appending some parameters in the Home page URL.

default URL: https://mytesting.com

after redirecting URL: https://mytesting.com/?someValue=123E234

I want to retrieve the "someValue" when I am landed to my default page (https://mytesting.com/?someValue=123E234) after redirecting. In java, we can retrieve it through a filter. In Angular, I am using Interceptor but the interceptor is never getting invoked and also don't know how do I achieve this with Interceptor

shared/exampleAuth.interceptor.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class ExampleAuth implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):
    Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    console.log('Checking Interceptor'); // This is never called
    return next.handle(request);
  }

}
```

home.componet

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
   })

   export class LoginComponent implements OnInit{
   constructor(private someservice: SomeotherService,
          private _router: Router) {

    ngOnInit() {
    window.location.href ="https://GoingforAuthentication.com"
     }


   }


  }
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [
    SomeotherService,
    ExampleAuth
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a need for you to use an interceptor. This logic would be specific to your component. You can subscribe to the observables present in `ActivatedRoute` to get the query params dynamically.

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
...

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(queryParam => {
      console.log(queryParam.someValue);
      // Do something with new query param here. Eg. update view, api call, etc.
    });
  }
```

This way even if you update the query param internally in your Angular code, you can update your view accordingly as you are subscribed to the query params.

Comment: Is there a particular event where you're redirecting the user to the external login? Like a login button?

Comment: Is not this the same I answered 2 hours before?

Comment: @Dimanoid - not exactly. Although your answer would work for this particular case, if the project is scaled and there ever comes a scenario where the query params are updated from within the component or by a child, the ````ngOnInit```` function would not be invoked thereby not changing the data accordingly if any. By subscribing, we tell Angular to "keep a lookout" for any changes on the query params and do the necessary changes.

Comment: In the question clearly stated that he redirects to `https://GoingforAuthentication.com` then back to his app at `https://mytesting.com` how in this scenario can happen "the query params are updated from within the component or by a child"? Your solution will lead to wrong behavior.

Comment: It wouldn't lead to wrong behavior because it does the same thing present in your solution, except that it subscribes to the query parameter in the URL making sure any further changes to the parameter would reflect in the component making it more dynamic. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't see how this would lead to wrong behavior.

Comment: The task required to handle auth token once, when auth service redirects back to the app, your code will be executed every change in params and may lead to authentication break and whole app misbehavior. If you dont see the difference I have nothing else to say.

Answer (score 0):

Change in `providers`:

```
ExampleAuth
```

to:

```
{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ExampleAuth, multi: true }
```

Check also this: https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses

Comment: Here is stackblitz with minimal setup - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckdw89

Comment: I have edited my question. I am using window.location.href to access the url. I even tried your sample code to access the URL with http.window. I  am getting thhis error  Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https:"https://GoingforAuthentication.com"    from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: I have to redirect the URL and the authentication part is done over there  and after sucessfull authentication re directed to home page.. I dont think with http calls we can do re direct..

Answer (score 0):

Http Interceptors used to intercept **your** requests through HttpClient's calls. What you need is just to check if you have required params in url when your app started. For this you need to inject `ActivatedRoute` service in your `app.component.ts`

```
constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute, ....) { ... }
```

and check for `someValue` in `ngOnInit`

```
ngOnInit() {
    const someValue = this._route.snapshot.queryParams['someValue'];
    if (someValue == '....') {
        // have been redirected from auth
    }
}
```

https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute

Comment: I have update the question.. I am redirecting the url through windows.location.href

Comment: You need to get the value from url when you get redirected BACK to your app from auth service, right? So it does not matter how you redirecting TO it...